# mysql workbench data import hangs forever

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench

My dump file is 76MB and it has generated in CentOS6 with follow command.

`$> mysqldump -uroot -p --routines testSchema > testSchema.sql`

And I am trying to import the file in my Windows7 with Workbench 6.3.

- pick `Import from Self-Contained File`
- Default Target Schema `testSchema` (I can see this schema on my left panel)
- Start Import

What I can see

- It execute the command `mysql.exe --default-file="somefile" --protocol=tcp --host=my_remote_db_host --user=my_user --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=testSchema < C:\my_dump_file`
- A progress bar with zero progress for an hour...
- `Status : starting` for an hour

I think it should throw an error or something. 
Since I can not find any error message on the screen,
I do not know what to do...

Is there any way what happens ?? or something wrong??